# What happens when a Polymorphed creature is reduced to 0 HP by Disintegrate?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Disintegrate and Polymorph both have effects that happen when the subject is reduced to 0 hit points.

Disintegrate says:

> If this damage reduces the target to 0 hit points, it is disintegrated.

Polymorph says:

> The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies.

Which takes precedence? Does Disintegrate reduce the a Polymorphed target to dust first or does the creature revert to its regular form first?

Comment: For future readers' reference: the answer to this question changed due to the 2018 PHB errata, so the existing answers here may have been rendered inaccurate by the change. As a result, this question has been closed as a duplicate of another question that asks how these 2 spells interact as of the 2018 errata.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### It takes exhausting both HP pools before you turn to dust.

[Apparently, RAI is in opposition to my other answer](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/644634544461737984) per a tweet from Mr Crawford (Credit to @Airatome for this tweet):

> **Jeremy Crawford**
>   <sup>@JeremyECrawford</sup>
>   The intent is that a druid using Wild Shape is disintegrated if
>   the druid, not the beast form, drops to 0 hp. #DnD
>   <sub>[3:10 PM - 17 Sep 2015](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/644634544461737984)</sub>
>
> > **Joshua Maxman**
> >     <sup>@Orethalion</sup>
> >     @JeremyECrawford What happens if a wild shaped druid is reduced to 0 by disintegrate?  Does he revert to normal physical form?
> >     <sub>[6:20 PM - 16 Sep 2015](https://twitter.com/Orethalion/status/644320091169951744)</sub>

This means that if you are under Polymorph, Wildshape, Shapechange, or True Polymorph, you'd trigger the "revert to your original form" condition once Disintegrate reduced you to 0 HP, and take any additional damage to your original form in excess of what it took to reduce you to zero from Disintegrate.

True Polymorph and Polymorph both say ...

> ... target assumes the hit points of its new form, and when it reverts to its normal form, the creature returns to the number of hit points it had before it transformed. If it reverts as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to its normal form. As long as the excess damage doesn’t reduce the creature’s normal form to 0 hit points, it isn’t knocked unconscious.

Wild Shape

> When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit
>   points you had before you transformed. However, if you revert as a
>   result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to
>   your normal form. For example, if you take 10 damage in animal form
>   and have only 1 hit point left, you revert and take 9 damage. As long
>   as the excess damage doesn’t reduce your normal form to 0 hit points,
>   you aren’t knocked unconscious.

Shapechange

> When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit
>   points you had before you transformed. If you revert as a result of 
>   dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your
>   normal form. As long as the excess damage doesn’t reduce your normal
>   form to 0 hit points, you aren’t knocked unconscious.

Per @Airatome's comment on Mr Crawford's tweet:

> I can't find a way to bring up the ENTIRE conversation, but it was noted this applies to Polymorph target's as well.

Comment: It seems this was errataed to be the other way around; from Sage Compendium (p. 13): "What happens if a druid using Wild Shape is reduced to 
0 hit points by disintegrate ? Does the druid simply leave beast form?
 The druid turns to dust, since the spell disintegrates you the instant you drop to 0 hit points."

Comment: @Kashir on page 14 of SA compendium Crawford provides a RAI and RAW PoV, which is why I have two answers. :)

Comment: Source link is dead

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Thanks, not sure if I can revive it; this is a good example of why it is important to avoid a link without a summary/sample of what's there.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I keep coming back to this answer every other week due to table arguments xD Where does JC provide a RAI and RAW PoV in the Sage Compendium? I only find the parts where Disintegrate kills Wild Shaped Druids and Half-Orcs

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Page 1 is where RAW and RAI are addressed.  SA seems to reflect RAI as often as it clears up what RAW means or meant.  What you need to do at your table is reach a consensus, and emphasize play rather than argument.  See also RAF.

Comment: 2018 errata fixed the RAW to specify this intended behaviour- [Does disintegrating a polymorphed enemy still kill it after the 2018 errata?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135856)

Answer (score 6):

### Dust to Dust: "Reduce to 0 hit points" & General vs Specific.

**Short Answer**

The target is Disintegrated/Dust, because this specific case of "reducing to 0 hit points" due to this spell is unique to this spell effect, versus the general case of what happens when a creature is reduced to 0 hit points.

> If this damage reduces the target to 0 hit points, it is disintegrated.  A disintegrated creature and everything it is wearing and carrying, except magic items, are reduced to a pile of fine gray dust.  The creature can be restored to life only by means of a true resurrection or a wish spell.

[The Sage Advice Compendium supports this answer from a RAW perspective](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=14):

> **What happens if a druid using Wild Shape is reduced to 0 hit points by disintegrate? Does the druid simply leave beast form?**
>   The druid turns to dust, since the spell disintegrates you the instant you
>   drop to 0 hit points.   That’s the literal interpretation of the rules
>   (RAW).
>
> In contrast, the intent (RAI) is that a druid isn’t considered to be
>   at 0 hit points for the purposes of an effect like disintegrate until
>   the druid’s normal form is reduced to 0 hit points.

There is some tension between this spell's result at 0 HP and the other shape changing methods.

Polymorph (both regular and true), Shapechange, and Wildshape all have a consistent rule of reverting to original form when 0 HP are reached, and can be summarized as follows:

> If you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form.  As long as the excess damage doesn’t reduce your normal form to 0 hit points, you aren’t knocked unconscious.

This answer favors Disintegrate because it bypasses, or renders null and void, considerations of the "unconscious" state at 0 HP.  This links in to the "what happens when you are reduced to 0 HP" rule.   You do not get the chance at a death saving throw, nor to stabilize in the disintegrate case.

> When you drop to 0 hit points, you either die outright or fall unconscious, as explained in the following sections.

The Disintegrate result overwrites the "fall unconscious" effect for the targeted creature.  The tension between the specific rules, over the general 0 HP rule, exists because Polymorph spells also overwrite unconscious because you don't fall unconscious when you revert to old form if the damage taken doesn't also exceed your normal HP.

Why favor Disintegrate?  *The transition phase still needs a creature* to make that happen.  With Disintegrate's spell effect, *there isn't a creature there any longer* to reform into an original form.  It seems valid to rule that disintegrate overrides the transitional form because it also destroys all non-magical equipment.  All of that is part of the pile of dust.  A pile of dust is not a creature.   Another nod to Disintegrate's power, and thus why it should take precedence, is that it takes a Wish or True Resurrection to come back from that. (That's powerful magic).

[Apparently, RAI is in opposition to my argument](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/644634544461737984?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) per a tweet from Mr Crawford (Credit to @Airatome for this tweet):

> Jeremy Crawford ‏@JeremyECrawford    Jeremy Crawford Retweeted Joshua
>   Maxman
>   The intent is that a druid using Wild Shape is disintegrated if
>   the druid, not the beast form, drops to 0 hp. #DnD   Jeremy Crawford
>   added,   Joshua Maxman @Orethalion
>   @JeremyECrawford What happens if a wild shaped druid is reduced to 0 by disintegrate?  Does he revert to normal physical form?
>   Retweet  3:10 PM - 17 Sep 2015

**Extended Answer**
Two cases:

- Player Characters

  See above
- All other Creatures

  Since all other creatures die at 0 HP (unless the DM makes a special case to have them follow PC rules) that shouldn't influence the above.

  > Monsters and Death
  >   Most GMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws.  Mighty villains and special nonplayer characters are common exceptions; the GM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters.

**Other considerations**

The spell effect changes a creature into a non-creature substance: dust.  It would be consistent to rule that no matter what shape change or polymorph power was being used, Disintegrate is a special case and the Specific beats General argument should prevail for it.

**Why not have it work the other way?**

Per the tweet linked, it appears that both Polymorphed cretaures and Wildshaped Druids would revert, rather than turn to dust, as RAI.

If one rules that way, True Polymorph, Polymorph, Wildshape, and Shapechange become special defenses against the Disintegrate spell, even though these spells already provide the added benefit of an extra HP pool for the creature in that shape.  Some will argue that this would move the "balance" in the direction of "unbalanced" or "too powerful."  Others won't.

The tweet favors the "specific" of polymorph/Wild Shape/Shapechange/True Polymorph, rather than the specific of *disintegrate,* requiring the exhaustion of both HP pools before being turned to dust by that spell.

Comment: Wanted to add:  https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/644634544461737984?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw

I can't find a way to bring up the ENTIRE conversation, but it was noted this applies to Polymorph target's as well.

Comment: So if I'm understanding right: Disintegrate could replace the 0 HP trigger and thus insta-kill morphed creatures, or Polymorph would have precedence. So I should ask my DM.

Comment: That's my take on it, though I will point out that Jeremy Crawford is a D&D dev.  You can argue RAI being for polymorph and the second pool of HP (which is a benefit of those spells and abilities) taking precedence.  Your DM will probably be interested to hear what the dev had to say on this.  I am making the case for Disintegrate, as a 6th level spell and it's stated effect of also destroying all of the equipment that isn't magical, being given precedence.

Comment: I definitely see the argument there. What if you cast Polymorph at 6th (I don't know rules for ties in spell level) or higher? Would that then let it take priority?

Comment: @Sawyer that's a good question, and also opens up my answer to the following criticism: in the case of True Polymorph and Shapechange, they are ninth level spells and as such would take precedence over a sixth level spell ... unless it was cast an 9th level to do more damage.  All of the issue  for those three spells leave the Wild Shape Druid class skill/ability open to "what level is that cast at?"  All of this detail diving violates KISS principle, which is why I tried to focus on the "spell effect" and its unusual " and your equipment too" detail as significant.

Comment: My only purpose was to add potential relevance from the Dev.  If you saw it as useful information or not.  Also take not that, he often prefaces by saying he helps interpret what their purpose was for the rules, it's not his job to enforce them.

Comment: The [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) changed *disintegrate* so it only disintegrates the target if it leaves the target with 0 HP, and the [2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) has been updated accordingly regarding Wild Shape. *Polymorph* follows the same logic in this case so the target wouldn't be disintegrated unless their original form's HP was reduced to 0 after they were reverted.

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, I'll look into this later, answer's kind of long, and possibly dated.

Answer (score 2):

You could see it as one of two things, though they both have very similar end results:

a) **The body simply disintegrates, and stays that way.** The Polymorph would not be able to reverse the disintegration spell since it isn't a True Resurrection Spell, or a Wish Spell.

> *(Taken from the Disintegrate spell)*
>   A disintegrated creature and everything it is wearing and carrying, except magic items, are reduced to a pile of fine gray dust. The creature can be restored to life only by means of a true resurrection or a wish spell.

or b) **The body polymorphs back into its original form, then it disintegrates.** The entire basis of the Disintegrate spell is to turn something to ash, and there doesn't seem to be anything in the polymorph spell that would counter that or stop the disintegration.

The differences are entirely for the roleplay description of the monster as it disintegrates, and the size of the ash-pile.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a polymorphed creature is never a "Huge or larger *object*".

Comment: Sorry, read the power wrong. I though it was referring to Huge or larger enemies and objects. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Polymorph spell's description. "The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points *or dies.*"

Thus reaching 0 HP will cause you to revert as will death. Yes, Disintegrate turns you to dust. It kills you. According to the Polymorph spell description, *death* will revert you to your original form with your original HP (with extra damage carried over).

There is nothing in the rules that says you cannot revert to your original form if you are no longer a "creature." The other answers seem to assume that as a rule and are forgetting that *death* in animal form is stated to also revert you, not just dropping to 0 HP.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and welcome to RPG StackExchange.  Civility in answers is a high priority on these boards so please consider referring to content in answers rather than referring to "you people" which can be interpreted as belittling: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice  In this particular case, the other answers are referring to the point that turning to dust occurs *after* the 0 hp according to the Disintegrate spell. The answers ask what comes first? Turning to dust - or - turning back to the original form? As noted, Jeremy Crawford had to clarify the order of the "stack."

Comment: Dropping to 0 HP won't outright kill you in all cases if you are a PC.  You go to the 0 HP rule if you are a PC.  The "or dies" can be applied to all creatures that are not a PC; those creatures usually die when dropped to 0 HP.   Granted, if the carry over HP from disintegrate reaches your max HP total, the dead the PC will be.  I have the idea that the "or dies" was for all other cases than PC, and the 0 HP was 'for all cases PC and those rare special NPC's that get to use the 0 HP rule."  Maybe I can get the dev to reply to that, or not.  I see your general point on spell text.

Comment: If you want to support your answer as written, suggest you refer to the sage advice compendium, page 14, since JCrawford covered both cases in that SA final draft.